# Node Js - require http is working without npm install but require express is not working

Tags: node.js, express

I created a simple project , by running npm init.

Now I got a folder

backend
->httpserver.js
->package.json

Inside, httpserver.js i had as below

```
var http = require("http");
//create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" }); // http header
    var url = req.url;
    if (url === "/about") {
      res.write("<h1>about us page<h1>"); //write a response
      res.end(); //end the response
    } else if (url === "/contact") {
      res.write("<h1>contact us page<h1>"); //write a response
      res.end(); //end the response
    } else {
      res.write("<h1>Hello World!<h1>"); //write a response
      res.end(); //end the response
    }
  })
  .listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("server start at port 3000"); //the server object listens on port 3000
  });
```

It worked perfect. WITHOUT DOING NPM INSTALL FOR HTTPSERVER
To my surprise, it worked even without a nodemodules folder.

But now, i removed the httpserver.js and added expserver.js which contains the below.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server running at 8000");
});
```

but this is erroring ,
"Cannot find module express"

I know i can do npm install to resolve it. But why dint it error out for httpserver ? Kindly help

Comment: `http` Is a built in node module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http` is a built-in module, so you can just `require()` it without having to install it.

`express` is not a built-in module so you have to first install it before you can `require()` it.

There are a significant number of built-in modules which you can see listed in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.html).  Any other 3rd party modules like Express you would have to install from NPM (or some other module source).

```
npm install express
```